# JMeter + Git + Jenkins + Maven

Tags: java, git, jenkins, jmeter

Я понимаю что есть возможность запуска Jmeter тестов на Jenkins с Git.
Но как это сделать - пока не понял, вроде надо через Pipeline , но не понимаю как(вроде в Jenkins нужно написать скрипт).

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, и было бы интересно узнать разъяснения почему так.

Проект на maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем можно сделать немного проще
в maven - pom единственное что надо вставить

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin - все написано тут

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <executions>
       <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
       <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
       </execution>
       <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
       <execution>
            <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>results</goal>
            </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

В проекте положить все тесты (*.jmx) по пути - `<Project Dir>/src/test/jmeter`

И в Jenkins в проекте со свободной конфигурацией(самый первый при создании нового item в Jenkins) добавить шаг сборки - maven и в поле цели написать - `verify`. + В jenkins надо указать свой maven - без этого у меня не запускались тесты.

Answer (score 0):

Подробная инструкция по запуску JMeter тестов из репозитория Git: [How to Run a JMeter Test with Jenkins 2.0 Pipelines and GitHub](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-test-jenkins-20-pipelines-and-github)

Единственное, что вам нужно сделать - это поменять структуру проекта для того чтобы она соответствовала требованиям [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin), то есть поместить скриты(ы) JMeter в папку `src/test/jmeter` и поменять способ запуска JMeter с `sh '/home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t /home/ubuntu/Jenkins_demo1.jmx -l test.jtl'` на `mvn clean verify`

Рекомендую еще интегрировать [Jenkins Performance Plugin](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html) чтобы можно было добавлять статистические таблицы и графики с трендами прямо на дашбоард билда

Comment: pipeline на groovy вроде, а я использовал maven.